# Unicode problem with CStdioFile in VC++

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to read in a URL such as http://google.com 
The Url is opened fined, and as soon as I read in the first line in the while(...)  loop, instead of getting some sensible characters representing html, I get weird Chinese characters into sCurlLine which is a CString. I think i am missing a unicode encoding/decoding part. 
The following is the simple code that reads a URL. The while loop reads line by line the file and the text is then updated into a text box.

Thanks for the help

```
  void CInetSessionDlg::OnBnClickedBurl()
    {
     CStdioFile * fpUrlFile;
     CString sCurlLine;
     UpdateData(TRUE);
     LPCTSTR url = m_sURL;
     fpUrlFile = m_misSession.OpenURL(url);

     if(fpUrlFile)
     {
      while(fpUrlFile->ReadString(sCurlLine))
      {
       m_sResult += sCurlLine;
       UpdateData(FALSE);
      }
     }

    }
```

Comment: Are you build unicode or ansi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are building is configured to use the correct project configuration settings.
Setting found: Project Properties|General|Project Defaults|Character Set

Maybe you have the wrong set "Not Set" | "Use Unicode"

Comment: Well I had to set the MultiByte Charater set. Thanks for the hint!